# styles/default.css in markup, where does it come from?

Tags: errors, 404-error, css, customization

I have the following line under the `head` tag but I don't have the file `styles/default.css` in my theme and consequently get a loading error in browsers. I'd like to eliminate this line but I don't know where it comes from. I tried to disable all plugins but it still appears. Is this a standard inclusion in WP?

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://wp.dev/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme1/styles/default.css">`

Comment: please give more specfic details and post at least the name and download link of your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it with `ack default.css`. In someone else's file that I had added to the theme.

Answer (score 1):

just guessing now because lack of info, but it could be in your functions.php and maybe called by the function "wp_enqueue_style()" or try to search your theme folder for default.css and it should give you that file where it being included from.

And no it is not a standard inclusion in WP.

Comment: I didn't find any of those, but ack came to the rescue. `ack default.css` found it. You were right, it's not part of the WP installation.